# CheckInstall fails to install on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, system-installation, python, checkinstall

I tried CheckInstall to track installation of package on Debian, but it fails to install it.
Installation follows the typical configure/make process

```
$ autoconf
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Therefore I just replaced `$ sudo make install` with `$ sudo checkinstall`. When I run `checkinstall` it start process of creating a package and start asking a series of questions. And here is where I made a mistake, I just wanted to build a package to add to my own system, not for distributing the finished package, so I just tried to accept the default answers, enter, etc.

I didn't specified "package version" (which is senseless for me), it started doing normal, but in the end CheckInstall complained that package version is missing, etc and installation failed.

It left the various orphaned files in the package folder: how to clean this, and how to proceed with this? Where Linux put files when installation fails: does it do same as Windows that store installation in temporary files and clean them out, so files is not remain in the system, or Linux keep these files and scatters them over the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `checkinstall` failed probably the package isn't installed, no need to remove, eventually try `sudo dpkg -r <package-name>`, and you can safely remove with `rm` intermediate files left in the directory.

The version is important for `dpkg`/`apt` so you must use one, even a fake, if tomorrow a package with the same name enter the distro, the one with the newer version will be installed.

Comment: I tried to remove with `dpkg -r` and it  return the package not installed.

Comment: In `dpkg` we trust, so wasn't installed :-)

Comment: So, just manually to remove CheckInstall files from package directory?

Comment: Yes that's it, is just some temporary/cache file `checkinstall` leave around, I'm sure `checkinstall` use `dpkg -i` to install the generated `.deb`, if `dpkg` say it isn't installed there should be nothing else left around. Curiosity, what the package you're trying to install?

Comment: that was binwalk.

Comment: Usually with *autotoolized* packages `checkinstall` works just fine, just give it a proper version. Else you could upgrade your Debian? In Jessie/Sid `binwalk` is already present (ready to install).

Comment: I reinstalled package successfully.